# Android - android.view.InflateException error When going to google maps the second time

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I have implemented a google map in my android app it is working fine for the first time. But when i try to go into it the second time,the app crashes.

I found out that i have to declare the supportFragment programatically without doind it in the xml.
But the solutions in stack overflow does not work for me because i'm accessing my google map in a class which is extended to a **PagerAdapter** . It does not support getChildFragmentManager(). How do i overcome this problem?

My class

```
    public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Fragment fragmentActivity;

    public ViewPageAdapter(ArrayList<BaseElement> item, int page,
                Activity activity, Fragment fragmentActivity) {
            super();
            this.item = item;
            this.page = page;
            this.activity = activity;
            this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            this.imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity);
        }

    @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    View view = null;


if (page == Element.THEATER_DETAIL.getType()) {


    GoogleMap googleMap = null;

                SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentActivity
                        .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);


                googleMap = fm.getMap();



                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(7.421226f, 80.401264f)).title("Hello world"));

                final LatLng SRILANKA = new LatLng(7.421226,80.401264);

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(SRILANKA)      // Sets the center of the map to SRILANKA
                .zoom(10)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(360)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            }
```

XML

```
<fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

logcat

```
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311):    at com.fortuna.cinemalk.adapter.ViewPageAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewPageAdapter.java:131)
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:829)
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:979)
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
01-05 17:00:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(16311):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:440)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the view ? you should add the view inside the instantiateItem function,

```
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name, null);
```

then continue with your code.

Comment: then how do I know where you are getting problem ?? Or paste your error log. please try to behave like developer and understand the need if you want to get your problem resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68256/discussion-between-crazydroid-and-chain).

Comment: sure. please come to chat